# Progress bar show only in debug mode. Job plus asynch Display

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

```
 Job job = new Job("Initialize Info ") 
 {

     @Override
     protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
     //some action in job thread

         Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {

             @Override
             public void run() {
                 //
                 //different actions with UI components.
             }
         });
      return Status.OK_STATUS;
      }
  };
  job.schedule();
```

When I run application in debug mode then progress bar is correctly displayed and all UI components waiting for a job. But in release mode UI components still waiting for a job but progress bar doesn't reflect.

What is the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to run `asycExec`. try use `UIJob`:
`The UIJob is a Job that runs within the UI Thread via an asyncExec.`
like this:

```
Job job = new Job("") {

    @Override
    protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
        monitor.beginTask("Task..." -1);
        // do what i need to do (and doesn't bother my UI)
        return Status.OK_STATUS;
    }
};

job.setUser(true);
job.schedule();
job.addJobChangeListener(new JobChangeAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void done(IJobChangeEvent event) {
        new UIJob("") {

            @Override
            public IStatus runInUIThread(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
                // Update my UI
                monitor.beginTask("UI Task..." -1);
                return Status.OK_STATUS;
            }
        }.schedule();
        super.done(event);
    }
});
```